# Pandas Pivot - "TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable"

Tags: python, sql, pandas, pivot, nonetype

Pandas read_SQL is not working, I am trying to access a SQL pivot function (Example 1). I have tried reading all the data but Pandas does not also process the data.

### EXAMPLE 1

```
sql_status_20 = """
SET NOCOUNT ON
USE [HilltopSamplerFix]

DECLARE @DynamicPivotQuery AS NVARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @ColumnName AS NVARCHAR(MAX)

select @ColumnName = STUFF((SELECT distinct ',' +
QUOTENAME(Name)
FROM [Hilltopsamplerfix].[dbo].[tempHilltopWaterQualityExtractAll]
FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)'), 1, 1, '');


SET @DynamicPivotQuery =
N'SELECT
SiteID,SiteName,RunDate,SampleTime,SampleID,' + @ColumnName + '
FROM [Hilltopsamplerfix].[dbo].[tempHilltopWaterQualityExtractAll]
PIVOT(max(Value)
FOR Name IN (' + @ColumnName + ')) AS PVTTable'

EXEC sp_executesql @DynamicPivotQuery
"""
connection_string = '...works...'
cnxn = pyodbc.connect(connection_string)
test = pd.read_sql(sql_status_20, cnxn)
cnxn.close()
```

### ERROR

columns = [col_desc[0] for col_desc in cur.description]

TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable

Comment: Please limit it to one question, eg split the second question on pivot_table to another question.

Comment: Regarding the first question, can you show the output of `cnxn.execute(sql_status_20).fetchall()` ? (this will test the query itself, without putting the data in a dataframe)

Comment: Thanks joris. The result from the fetchall() "pyodbc.ProgrammingError: No results.  Previous SQL was not a query." It appears python is not able to process advanced queries. The query works in Studio manager.

Answer (score 0):

Old question, but I had the same issue as mentioned above. The problem lies in the `USE [HilltopSamplerFix]`. The database name is already mentioned in the connectionstring, so this part can be removed.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue, and removing the USE [DatabaseName] clause fixed the issue. I also had the Database specified in my connection string.